# FDT 3 Enterprise, can't add breakpoints

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse, fdt

I've been using FDT for a long long time, on my new machine, with the Enterprise edition, I cannot add breakpoints on the editors gutter, and the debugger doesn't show any variables when testing with the external player.

Any ideas on how to fix, is it some obscure Eclipse setting, or and FDT setting?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the FDT perspective? Maybe you havn't installed a debug flash player in your browsers (external player utilises browser plugin)? Maybe you havn't provided a valid registration key? Maybe you does not use the most recent version but a beta version?

If you think it is a bug you might report it: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT